# Is covariance a measure of effect size?

Tags: covariance, effect-size

Is covariance a measure of effect size?  Since correlation is such a measure, and correlation is normalized covariance, I would think so, but I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: "Effect" of what?  To be understood, this term needs a context. What is your null hypothesis and what is the alternative?

Comment: Effect sizes are frequently about differences in means (e.g. the mean difference between treatment and control). See this question, [Non-transitivity of correlation: correlations between gender and brain size and between brain size and IQ, but no correlation between gender and IQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/131065/1036), for discussion on why  correlations/covariances typically say nothing about the means.