# Can two random variables, both of which are dependent on a 3rd random variable, be independent of each other?

Tags: random-variable, independence

Let's say we have three random variables $X, Y, Z$.

We know that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, and also that $Y$ and $Z$ are dependent.

Under this setting, is it possible for $X$ and $Z$ to be independent?

(Intuitively, I think the answer is no. Knowing the value of $X$ would give us some information about $Y$, which in turn would give us some information of $Z$, making $X$ and $Z$ dependent. Although I can't seem to prove it.)

Comment: Intuitively, the part of Y that correlates with X can be different from the part of Y that correlates with Z, such that X and Z are independent of each. So this is very common. In fact, it is the situation in which ANCOVA is recommended; X is categorical, while Z and Y are continuous.

Comment: Imagine $X$ and $Z$ are the result of independent coin flips. Can you define $Y$ in such a way that it depends on both $X$ and $Z$?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. Two examples:

**Discrete example** Throw two coins independently, but code the outcomes as 0 or 1. Then define:

$$ \begin{align} X&=\text{outcome on first coin}\\
                 Y&=\text{sum of both outcomes}\\
                 Z&=\text{outcome on second coin} 
\end{align} $$

**Continuous variable example** Let $(x,Y,Z)$ have the multivariate normal distribution
$$ (X,Y,Z) \sim \mathcal{MN}(\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&1/2&0\\1/2&1&1/2\\0&1/2&1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Your arguments in your last paragraph can be formulated as a question? *Is independence transitive*?  which leads to the analogous question [Non-transitivity of correlation: correlations between gender and brain size and between brain size and IQ, but no correlation between gender and IQ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131065/non-transitivity-of-correlation-correlations-between-gender-and-brain-size-and)