# How to draw nice graphical models?

Tags: data-visualization, graphical-model

Many statistical papers or articles present very nice draws of graphical models.

Example: this on LDA from wikipedia

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation.svg/250px-Latent_Dirichlet_allocation.svg.png

or this, pg 7, directly from the paper:

http://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/5f10/38ad42ed8a4428e395c96d57f83d201ef3b3.pdf

I am now writing a paper where I have to introduce a new graphical model. If I try to draw it, say with paint, something very horrible comes out (see my other posts)

So I am wondering: which tool use statisticians to draw such nice models in their papers?

Comment: What do you consider nice?

Comment: Publication quality. 

Look at this post of mine: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272122/fitting-partially-observed-mixture-models

the quality of the chart is very poor, if compared with the linked images, and I can not add it on a paper.

Comment: I've voted as a [duplicate of this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16750/1036). The answers there give many different suggestions.